# Multiple option for val in a bundle

Tags: chisel

I tried to add some generation options to my bundle code:

```
class myIO (val bitwidth: Int,numOfInstances: Int = 1) extends Bundle {
   val en   = if (numOfInstances == 1) Bool(INPUT) else Vec(numOfInstances,Bool(INPUT))
   val data = UInt(INPUT,bitwidth.W)
   ...
}
```

when I tried

```
val io = IO(new myIO(32)) // use default
```

I get compilation error "type missmatch" io.en is chisel3.core.Data but chisel3.Bool is required. Also when trying :

```
val io = IO(new myIO(32,1))
```

I got the same error

Comment: Please note that Scala is a statically-type language (which IMO is really a great thing!). The type of the `if` statement would be the superset of `Bool` and Vec branches which is `Data` and cannot turn into a hardware type. Conceptually that doesn't make much sense either.I guess you can either a) stick with Vec and one-bit case is just a Vec with length 1, b) create two different IO classes, or maybe a class `myIO` with `Vec` and another subclass myIOSingleInstnce were `val en` is Bool

Comment: As a side-note, in chisel3, you should use `Input()` and `Output()` macros instead of the direction arguments.

Comment: Hi Kamyar , what you say make sense thanks. I also think you can post it as the answer to this question.